# How do I create a link to an answer?

Tags: support, formatting, hyperlinks

At this point I know how to add a clickable link in my answer, and I can create such a link to a question by copying the URL from the top of the browser. But if I want to make reference to someone else's answer, how do I create a clickable link to it?

Comment: Related: If you want links in comments to be auto-prettified, i.e. turned into text links (like the following one), check out [SE Comment Link Helper](http://stackapps.com/q/2378).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Each question and answer has a `share` link underneath it.  If you click on that, a small box with a link will pop up. You can then simply copy that link and paste into your answers.

[image: picture of share link]

It's helpful to insert the question itself as the text of the link. You do this in markup in the following way:

```
[ text here ](link here)
```

If the link is to a question, then the title of that question will be automatically inserted. So

```
 https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1139/83 ask about linking to answers.
```

will display as

> [How do I create a link to an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1139/83) ask about linking to answers.

Comment: See also [Automatic question's title insertion with link](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2456/5701) about automatic titles.

Comment: Nowadays the button `link` is renamed in `share`...

Comment: @e-birk Thanks for the comment.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think renaming `link` to `share` was a mistake. I have often wanted to create a link to an answer, and not known how to find the link. I had always assumed that the `share` button would give me options to connect to Facebook, Twitter, and so on, which I never use. The word `link` is much more appropriate for this feature.

Answer (score 3):

There is now a stackapp Greasemonkey script which will give you a `copy` button similar to the `link` button below posts:
[Copy Question Link Markdown - Making it easier to copy links to questions!](https://stackapps.com/q/2150/10230)
It provides you with the `[<title>](<url>)` format required. You can use it in comments and also in question or answer posts.

I found a few issues with the script and rewrote parts of it. The revised version can be found [as answer to the above stackapps post](https://stackapps.com/a/3318/10230).