# Automatic question's title insertion with link

Tags: support, formatting, hyperlinks

I know how to insert a `[link](link)` in my questions, answers or comments, and I know how to use `tex.stackexchange link` button as explained in [How do I create a link to an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1141/1952).

But I need to use two copy+paste operations, one for `[this is my question]` and a second for `(link to this is my question)`.

Is it possible to do it with just one operation? How?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In questions and answers you can simply insert the plain link to a question or answer and it will be converted to a link to that question labeled with the title of it. This works for both full and compact links but it does not work in comments.

For example if you insert

```
https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2456/automatic-questions-title-insertion-with-link
```

into a question or answer it will be converted to

> [Automatic question's title insertion with link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2456/automatic-questions-title-insertion-with-link)

The same goes for compact links (but not for answers). For example if you insert

```
https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2456
```

into a question or answer it will be converted to

> [Automatic question's title insertion with link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2456)

Comment: Thank you. I will use this syntax. I couldn't find it in [Markdown Editing Help](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: @Ignasi I think its implementation is noted in [Replace trilogy raw links with the current question title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/69483#69483)

Answer (score 7):

As already stated by N.N. it is sufficient to simply post a link to the question or answer into a question or answer post. It will be formatted automatically. However, in the recent past this didn't worked for my 100% the time. You might try to add `< >` around the link. Also, this does not work for comments.

Therefore I can recommend the following:
There is a stackapp Greasemonkey script which will give you a `copy` button similar to the `link` button below posts:
[Copy Question Link Markdown - Making it easier to copy links to questions!](https://stackapps.com/q/2150/10230)
It provides you with the `[<title>](<url>)` format required. You can use it in comments and also in question or answer posts.

I found a few issues with the script and rewrote parts of it. The revised version can be found [as answer to the above stackapps post](https://stackapps.com/a/3318/10230).

[image: Screeenshot]

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it!