# Comments with link (Policy or Feature Request): Automatically rendered as question's title or answerer username

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

As discussed at Question: [Automatic question's title insertion with link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2456/15717), question/answer url links in comments does not automatically render as titles or answer usernames.

A [Workaround pointed out by doncherry](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1139/how-do-i-create-a-link-to-an-answer/1141#comment10975_1139) is [SE Comment Link Helper](https://stackapps.com/questions/2378/se-comment-link-helper).

**Should we have this feature request  in comments while posting duplicates/related** incase of instances like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107142/mathtime-professional-ii-lite-font-weight/107143#comment233711_107143),[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109105/using-square-bracket-inside-square-bracket#comment239093_109105) and [there](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3434/15717) with many *[this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2475/15717) vs [more helpfull stackapps and scripts](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2475/useful-stackapps-and-other-user-scripts-for-tex-sx) than here there etc... as titles*

**or**

**Should we adopt community agreed policy to have something like below due to the fact that**

a)url does not mean anything or convey any message unless CLICKED on and searched to the pointer given in section pointer guide.

b)improve readability of comments as comments give crucial info and sometimes more valuable than answers due to one-liners

b) sometimes people don't open the links incase of bunch of urls.

c) It's important in view that we have many duplicates coming due to large database builtup.

d) Does it effect the Google or TeX.SX searchability when typed with keywords, because urls are not searchable right ?

**probable format: to improve readability of comments**

1) `[short title](url)` ---> title based

2)`[Answer by username to "Question title"](url)` ----> username based

3)`[topic(tex distro installation) related ](url)`-------> topic based

4)`[your proposed choice](url)`----> your choice

PS: Forgive me that i had to too same redirection of links as noticed. Usually i tool fall prey for this url trick

Comment: Google index the site within seconds, I believe they are well aware of the equivalent ways to make an url. This is certainly not an issue.

Comment: why depend on others when we can make ourselves clean with tiny bit of care to paste [Title](url) as it makes more sense.

Comment: That was a comment to your question d).

Answer (score -3):

In my opinion, request for automated modification of comments in this manner is unnecessary and at least for me, frowned upon, I hate a lot all such systems that try to be more clever than me, when they aren't. Hover text with the question title and/or answer's owner would be completely enough.

Comment: The hover text (derived from the URL) is already implemented *iff* you use the full URL of the question: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1139/how-do-i-create-a-link-to-an-answer (`http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1139/how-do-i-create-a-link-to-an-answer`)

Comment: @doncherry Then the request should be for making it work for all links back into StackExchange, not only for some of them :-/

Comment: But then we could as well turn them into the proper titles all the way (which I wouldn’t be opposed to)‽ Btw, does it also bother you that links to questions in posts (not comments) are “smartly” turned into the respective titles? I don’t really see that as the system trying to be smarter than me, but rather as mindless work being done for me by a computer, thankfully. (Also btw: the downvote isn’t mine.)

Comment: @doncherry Links to questions are turned automatically only when I don't use the `[]()` syntax, aren't they? Or do I miss something?

Comment: That’s correct. Autoconverting something tha already is in a explicit link format would indeed be useless outsmarting.